# Is this a sufficient condition for differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that, for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$, every vector in $f^{-1}(c)$ is supported by a ***unique*** hyperplane to $f^{-1}(c)$.

Is $f$ differentiable?

I'd be grateful for any references.

Comment: Remind us what it means to be supported by a hyperplane?

Answer (score 1):

Restrict attention to the class of hyperplanes $H=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle p,x\rangle = 1\}$, where $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

For $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a point $x$ on the boundary of $A$ is supported by a hyperplane $H$ to $A$ if there exists $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\langle p,x\rangle =1$ and $\langle p,y\rangle \geq 1$ for all $y\in A$.

Given $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that every $x\in f^{-1}(c)$ is supported by a unique (in this class) hyperplane $H$ to $f^{-1}(c)$, is it the case that $f$ is differentiable?